# iPhone App Icon is not taking up the full space for the icon on springboard?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, icons

My app icon for iPhone 4 is 114x114 Pixels, 72 DPI and named Icon@2x.png, But it's not taking up the full space for the icon, anyone know whats going on?

Comment: I figured it out, I had put both 114x114 and 57x57 in the project thinking I needed both if one wasn't a retina display. Deleted the 57x57 and it is showing correct now. Thanks for everyone's quick reply. I can't "answer" my own question yet lol. I'll give you all credit, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could either be that your icon is not properly set in the Xcode Project (i.e., the wrong icon is getting used by default).

Or your icon is not a perfect square. If you try and round the icon yourself, it's possible that there will be a discrepancy between your rounding and Apple's rounding, and whitespace could appear.

Comment: So if your rounding the icon yourself, do you know what the pixel size should be?

Comment: Not sure really. I would play with the sizes to try and cover the gaps where you're seeing whitespace. But unless you do that with all dozen-some sizes of icon that iOS uses, you're probably going to run into issues. Looks like Moshe left a resource for custom rounding that might worth looking at, but short of that, I would suggestion using a square icon and letting iOS do its thing.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check the case of image filename. It should be lowercase, afair
2. Check exact dimensions of image, it should be 57x57 for icon.png and 114x114 for icon@2x.png
3. Do you ship low-res icon.png with your app?
4. Try to remove dpi value or set it to 320 (for iPhone retina display)

Answer (score 1):

Check your Xcode project, your filepath and filename. Assuming that those are all correct, look into your icon design. You can see the correct radii for custom rounding on your icons [on this page](http://hicksdesign.co.uk/iconreference/).